# Derivative of $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(xt)}{t^{2}}dt$

Tags: real-analysis

I just wanna know if my intuition is right, I have the integral:
$$
F(x)=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(tx)}{t^{2}}dt
$$
I want to find $F'(x)$. I claim the answer to be $0$, heres why:
$$
\frac d{dx}\int_{\alpha(x)}^{\beta(x)}f(t)dt = \beta'(x)\cdot f(\beta(x)) - \alpha'(x)\cdot f(\alpha(x))
$$
Then what we have here essentially is $\alpha'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}0=0$.
Now I either solved it correctly, or did something stupid. Hope someone can confirm for me.

Comment: Your derivative of beta could be seen as little stu...

Comment: I see we should do partial derivative inside integral right? @Troposphere

Comment: HAHAHAHHAHAHA @hamam_Abdallah

Comment: Ahh now it makes sense @Troposphere therefore, the answer should make sense now thank youu

Comment: Comment upgraded to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$F'(x)$ certainly cannot be $0$ everywhere, since $F(0)=1$ is easily computed, and $F(x)\to 0$ for $x\to\infty$ since the ever closer neigboring wiggles of the cosine tend to cancel each other out the more there are of them.

The error in your reasoning is that you have forgotten that your $f$ is a function of *both* $x$ and $t$. What you really have is
$$\frac d{dx}\int_{\alpha(x)}^{\beta(x)}f(t,x)\,dt = \beta'(x)\cdot f(\beta(x),x) - \alpha'(x)\cdot f(\alpha(x),x)+\int_{\alpha(x)}^{\beta(x)} \Bigl[\frac{d}{dx} f(t, x)\Bigr] \, dt$$

---

Here's a heuristic estimate of $F(x)$  when $x\gg0$. Perhaps that can tell you enough about the general shape of the derivative for your purposes:

If $x$ is large, the integrand consists of a lot of narrow positive and negative peaks of the cosine numerator. The with of each half-period is $\frac{\pi}{x}$. If we flip the sign of every other half-period and slide each of them to cover the interval $t\in[1,1+\frac\pi x]$, the entire integral is the area between *every other* of the resulting curves -- and therefore tends to simply half of integral of the *first* half-period.

Within the first period the $\frac1{t^2}$ factor is eventually just $1$, so we can calculate
$$ F(x) \approx \frac12 \int_{1}^{1+\pi/x} \cos(xt)\,dt = \frac{\sin(x+\pi)-\sin(x)}{2x} 
= \frac{-\sin(x)}{x} $$

Comment: Also the answer here is it in terms of elementary functions or should it be $0$ as I predicted? An online calculator is giving me the answer in terms of $\Gamma$ function,

Comment: It’s definitely not $0,$ @deerclaysup The integral remaining in this answer is non-zero.

Comment: Oh you are correct

Comment: @deerclaysup: It certainly can't be $0$ since $F(0)=1$ is easily computed and $F(x)\to 0$ for $x\to \infty$ because the up-down wiggles of the cosine end up canceling out pairwise. It sounds pretty expected to me that it doesn't have a nice elementary answer, though.

Comment: +1 Beautiful analysis

Comment: @deerclaysup: It was faulty, but I've corrected it. The first partial wiggle turns out to be important.

Answer (score 1):

A formal differentiation under the integral suggests that
$$
F'(x) = -\int_1^\infty {\sin(xt)\over t} dt.
$$
One problem with a direct attack on this, using dominated convergence, for example, is that this integral doesn't converge absolutely. Taking a step back,  rewrite $F$ using one integration by parts:
$$
F(x) = -{\sin x\over x}+{2\over x}\int_1^\infty {\sin(xt)\over t^3} dt.
$$
Differentiation of *this* integral
$$
G(x):=\int_1^\infty {\sin(xt)\over t^3} dt.
$$
can be justified by dominated comvergence and the result is
$$
G'(x)=\int_1^\infty {\cos(xt)\over t^2} dt=F(x).
$$
Thus, because
$$
F(x) =-{\sin x\over x}+{2\over x}G(x)
$$
you have
$$
\eqalign{
F'(x) 
&= {\sin x-x\cos x\over x^2} + {2\over x}F(x) -{2\over x^2}G(x)\cr
&={\sin x-x\cos x\over x^2}+ {2\over x}F(x) -{2\over x^2}\left[{x\over 2}F(x)+{\sin x\over 2} \right]\cr
&= -{\cos x\over x}+{1\over x}F(x).
}
$$
Finally, again integrating by parts,
$$
F(x) :=\int_1^\infty{\cos(xt)\over t^2} dt= \cos x-x\int_1^\infty{\sin (xt)\over t}dt
$$
so
$$
\eqalign{
F'(x) 
&= -{\cos x\over x}+{1\over x}F(x)=-{\cos x\over x}+{1\over x}\left[ \cos x-x\int_1^\infty{\sin (xt)\over t}dt\right]\cr
&=-\int_1^\infty{\sin(xt)\over t} dt,\cr
}
$$
as suspected